# How do you know if something is supported by Microsoft?

Tags: exchange

I was reading on Technet about how to put Exchange on the Internet via the Hub Transport Server role. The article explains that though this is not the best or recommended way of doing things they also know not everyone has two servers to split up Exchange services.

But how do I know if what I am reading on Microsoft's site is supported or just telling me how to do something? If I call them with a problem later one will they say, "that's not supported"? I can't tell.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123494.aspx

This is not really an Exchange question, just an example, and how do I know if something is supported or not.

Comment: how is this not a real question?

Comment: How about you READ it. IT is quite clear in the formulations what it is. If you ever had some school training or be reading some books and documentation - msdn is actually a lot better than the rest. Common sense, and understanding of sentences actually help you understand the meaning of something published.

Answer (score 6):

1. Contact Microsoft support.
2. Ask them if article XYZ or configuration ABC is supported.
3. Request they send confirmation to you in writing.

Comment: Basically this is about the only way to know with any degree of certainty.

Comment: In general this is the only way to determine if $_VENDOR supports $_PRODUCT.  As jscott said, get it in writing: Email may be OK, but ink on company letterhead with a signature is worth its weight in the corpses of first-tier support folks.

Comment: @voretaq7: so, a few hundredths of a gram? Printing ink is not very heavy... ;)

Comment: a few hundredths of a gram of tetrodotoxin is all you need ;)